# Multiplying columns in SQLite3 from two different tables

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am currently working on a school project where I must develop a database application with a graphical user interface using Python, Tkinter, and SQLite3. The user enters the ProductID and quantity into a form, and I am trying to get the program to select the price of the product from the product table using the ProductID, and multiply this price by the quantity input by the user to give the total cost of the order and insert this result into the total field on the order table.

I am receiving the following error:

```
  File "c:\Users\Ryan\OneDrive - C2k\A2 2020-2021\Computer Science\A2 Unit 5\Code\OrderForm.py", line 81, in CalculatePrice
    price = ((int(quantity)*(int(x) for x in results)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'generator'
```

I have carried out research into this error, however, I still cannot understand how to get this to work or if it is even possible. If anybody could take a look at my code below and try help me out with doing this, I would really appreciate it.

```
    def CalculatePrice(self):
        orderid = self.OrderIDEntry.get()
        productid = self.ProductIDEntry.get()
        quantity = self.QuantityEntry.get()
        with sqlite3.connect("LeeOpt.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            searchprice = ('''SELECT Price FROM Products WHERE ProductID = ?''')
            cursor.execute(searchprice, [(productid)])
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            
            if results:
                for i in results:
                    price = ((int(quantity)*(int(x) for x in results)))
                    addprice = ('''INSERT INTO Orders(OrderTotal)
                    VALUES (?)''')
                    cursor.execute(addprice, [(price)])
                    self.ClearEntries()
            else:
                tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "No product was found with this ProductID, please try again.")
                self.ClearEntries()
```

[image: Order Form]

Comment: Assuming `ProductID` is unique, `searchprice` is going to return one price ... you are looping  multiple times over `results`. `price = int(searchprice[0][0]) * int(quantity)` should be sufficient.

Comment: You should subdivide the task. First try to set a variable with the price of product with a given product id. **Then** do the calculation for this product, **then** insert the result into the orders table. Check success e. g. with "print" for each step.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Yes ProductID is unique. I understand your explanation, thank you! I'll try this now.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I understand, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing an external loop over the `results` iterable, inserting 1 value at a time, and an execution of the same `INSERT` query over an iterable of values.

First way, external loop (I have removed some useless parentheses):

```
            for i in results:
                price = int(quantity)*int(i)
                addprice = ('''INSERT INTO Orders(OrderTotal)
                VALUES (?)''')
                cursor.execute(addprice, [price])
```

Second way, using `executemany`:

```
            prices = ([int(quantity)*int(x)] for x in results)  # prices is an iterable of lists
            addprice = ('''INSERT INTO Orders(OrderTotal)
            VALUES (?)''')
            cursor.executemany(addprice, prices)
```

But if you are learning SQL and database accesses, you could directly use joined queries:

```
addprice = '''INSERT INTO Orders(OrderTotal)
    SELECT :quantity * Price FROM Products
    WHERE Products.ProductID = :productid'''
cursor.execute(addprice, {'quantity': quantity, 'productid': productid})
```

And as your code contains an (unused) `orderid` variable, I think that what you want is:

```
addprice = '''INSERT INTO Orders(OrderID, OrderTotal)
    SELECT :orderid, :quantity * Price FROM Products
    WHERE Products.ProductID = :productid'''
cursor.execute(addprice, {'quantity': quantity, 'productid': productid,
                          'orderid': orderid})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expressions `(int(x) for x in results)` and `(int(quantity)*(int(x) for x in results))` evaluates to a generator objects as you have enclosed it within parenthesis. See here

```
>>> (quant for quant in range(5))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1021e1780>
>>>
```

So remove your parenthesises and break it down into smaller chunks.
Also there should only be one price returned for a single productId, so you're looping multiple times and don't have to use tuples unless you're input itself is multiple product ids and you're multiplying each price and product and computing order total.
A simplified version might look like this

```
        cursor.execute('SELECT Price FROM Products WHERE ProductID = ?', (productid,))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        
        if result:
            price = quantity * float(result[0])
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Orders(OrderTotal) VALUES (?)', (price,))
            self.ClearEntries()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "No product was found with this ProductID, please try again.")
            self.ClearEntries()
```

Comment: I am receiving the following error upon running this code. Any ideas why? `  File "c:\Users\Ryan\OneDrive - C2k\A2 2020-2021\Computer Science\A2 Unit 5\Code\OrderForm.py", line 79, in CalculatePrice
    price = quantity * float(result)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'`

Comment: Yes, the row/result is a tuple sorry, so you need to retrieve the first element, result[0] should return the price.